# Notification with every end of month

Tags: android, notifications

This is what i want add to my app. Notification with every end of month.

**Example:** Tomorrow is 1st day of next month. I want to show notification end day of month 28 or 29 for FEB, 30 or 31 for other months.
How can i do this?
help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using AlarmManager but problem with only February month. 
you can use like this for setAlarm for every month unfortunately don't know how can handle for February.  I think you can set Condition for February particularly .

```
alarmStartTime.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 30);
```

Comment: Thanks Bro. I'll try. :)